# Granting permission to ALL objects in a bucket via AWS Powershell Tools?

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, acl, aws-powershell

I can grant specific permissions to a specific file easily, like this:

```
Set-S3ACL -BucketName "bucket" -Key "file.txt"
```

However, now I'm trying to do it for all the files:

```
Set-S3ACL -BucketName "bucket" -Key "*"
```

This does not work and it throws:

```
Set-S3ACL : The specified key does not exist.
```

What is the valid syntax in this case?

Comment: Since `Key` does not accept wildcard input, I suspect you'll have to pipe the results and do it one at a time. If you can describe how you get `file.txt`, I can write up a solution.

Comment: The files are a website, essentially. I'm using a pipeline to build my react app and upload the build folder to an S3 bucket in a different account. So I'm trying to give it permission to upload it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to recursively apply the function to every file, you can achieve that with `Get-ChildItem` to get all of the files in a folder, and using `Recurse` to also search subfolders. Then loop those results and call the function for each one.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $topfolder -Recurse | ForEach-object { Set-S3ACL -BucketName "bucket" -Key $_.Name }
```